# Evaluation of nested IF in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I found this code in a WordPress plugin, but I cannot understand what does it mean or how it can be read.

Can somebody to help me underdstaint this code :?

```
IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users = 0, TRUE, IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users_reg = 1, IF(agr_sam_ads.x_ad_users = 1, NOT FIND_IN_SET("admin", agr_sam_ads.x_view_users), TRUE ....
```

I have not paste the whole query because it is huge. In what I am interested to be helped is the part of the Query that looks like that:

```
IF(expression, value, IF(expression, IF(expression, SQL Logical Query, value ...
```

I have not see this syntax, and I don't know where to search for that. In MySQL documentation the IF statement syntax is like that : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html and it is not looks like the one I have paste above.

Just for the users are interested in the full code, the code is here:

```
SELECT 
agr_sam_places.id, 
agr_sam_places.name, 
agr_sam_places.description, 
agr_sam_places.code_before, 
agr_sam_places.code_after, 
agr_sam_places.place_size, 
agr_sam_places.place_custom_width, 
agr_sam_places.place_custom_height, 
agr_sam_places.patch_img, 
agr_sam_places.patch_link, 
agr_sam_places.patch_code, 
agr_sam_places.patch_adserver, 
agr_sam_places.patch_dfp, 
agr_sam_places.patch_source, 
agr_sam_places.trash, 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        agr_sam_ads 
    WHERE 
        agr_sam_ads.pid = agr_sam_places.id 
    AND 
        agr_sam_ads.trash IS FALSE
) AS ad_count, 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        agr_sam_ads 
    WHERE 
        agr_sam_ads.pid = agr_sam_places.id 
    AND 
        agr_sam_ads.trash IS FALSE 
    AND 
        (
            IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users = 0, TRUE, IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users_reg = 1, IF(agr_sam_ads.x_ad_users = 1, NOT FIND_IN_SET("admin", agr_sam_ads.x_view_users), TRUE
        ) 
    AND 
        IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users_adv = 1, (agr_sam_ads.adv_nick <> "admin"), TRUE), FALSE))) 
    AND 
        (
            (
                agr_sam_ads.view_type = 1
            ) 
        OR 
            (
                agr_sam_ads.view_type = 0 
            AND 
                (
                    agr_sam_ads.view_pages+0 & 256
                )
            )
        ) 
    AND 
        (
            agr_sam_ads.ad_cats = 0
        ) 
    AND 
        (
            agr_sam_ads.ad_authors = 0
        ) 
    AND 
        IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_schedule, CURDATE() BETWEEN agr_sam_ads.ad_start_date AND agr_sam_ads.ad_end_date, TRUE) 
    AND 
        IF(agr_sam_ads.limit_hits, agr_sam_ads.hits_limit > agr_sam_ads.ad_hits, TRUE) 
    AND 
        IF(agr_sam_ads.limit_clicks, agr_sam_ads.clicks_limit > agr_sam_ads.ad_clicks, TRUE) 
    AND 
        (
            agr_sam_ads.ad_weight > 0
        )
) AS ad_logic_count, 
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        agr_sam_ads 
    WHERE 
        agr_sam_ads.pid = agr_sam_places.id 
    AND 
        agr_sam_ads.trash IS FALSE 
    AND 
        (
            IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users = 0, TRUE, IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users_reg = 1, IF(agr_sam_ads.x_ad_users = 1, NOT FIND_IN_SET("admin", agr_sam_ads.x_view_users), TRUE) 
        AND 
            IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_users_adv = 1, (agr_sam_ads.adv_nick <> "admin"), TRUE), FALSE))) 
        AND 
            (
                (
                    agr_sam_ads.view_type = 1
                ) 
            OR 
                (
                    agr_sam_ads.view_type = 0 
                AND 
                    (
                        agr_sam_ads.view_pages+0 & 256
                    )
                )
            ) 
        AND 
            (
                agr_sam_ads.ad_cats = 0
            ) 
        AND 
            (
                agr_sam_ads.ad_authors = 0
            ) 
        AND 
            IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_schedule, CURDATE() BETWEEN agr_sam_ads.ad_start_date AND agr_sam_ads.ad_end_date, TRUE) 
        AND 
            IF(agr_sam_ads.limit_hits, agr_sam_ads.hits_limit > agr_sam_ads.ad_hits, TRUE) 
        AND 
            IF(agr_sam_ads.limit_clicks, agr_sam_ads.clicks_limit > agr_sam_ads.ad_clicks, TRUE) 
        AND 
            IF(agr_sam_ads.ad_weight > 0, (agr_sam_ads.ad_weight_hits*10/(agr_sam_ads.ad_weight*1000)) < 1, FALSE)
    ) AS ad_full_count 
FROM 
    agr_sam_places 
WHERE 
    agr_sam_places.id = 10 
AND 
    agr_sam_places.trash IS FALSE;
```

Comment: How does a new user have a rep of 2915?

Comment: New in MySQL, not in StackOverflow ;) , I just fixed the title to help you :)

Comment: *"Just for the users interested in the **fool** code ..."* Wisely stated.

Comment: There is `IF` statement (with the link you have) and the **[`IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)**. This query uses the function, not the statement.

Comment: I didn't knew that MySQL has IF() function !!! Thanks @ypercube. This solves my problem :) I you like, post this as answer to upvote you. Thanks ... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be read as:

```
IF (
    expression, 
    valueIfExpressionIsTrue, 
    valueIfExpressionIsValue
)
```

So to take part of your code:

```
IF(
    agr_sam_ads.ad_users = 0,
    TRUE,
    IF(
        agr_sam_ads.ad_users_reg = 1,
        2,
        3
    )
)
```

I see that you're familiar with PHP, so essentially if this was PHP, the code would be

```
if ($arg_sam_ads_ad_users == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    if ($arg_sam_ads_ad_users_reg == 1) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically creating an IF-ELSE tree without using the IF _ THEN _ ELSE _ ENDIF syntax.

Take the following example:

```
IF(1=0, 1, IF(1=1, 1, 0))
```

This is the equivalent of the following with C syntax:

```
IF (1=0) {
  1
}
ELSE IF (1=1) {
  1
}
ELSE {
  0
}
```

The more common SQL syntax is the following:

```
IF 1=0 THEN
  1;
ELSEIF 1=1 THEN
  1;
ELSE
  0;
ENDIF;
```

Comment: Not completely correct. It isn't an `} ELSE IF () {` - it's an `} ELSE { IF () {`.

Comment: I had a syntax error in my answer. While what you say is correct, there is an ELSEIF keyword (Not ELSE IF like I originally posted).